# how to get Lifecycle states of a Mule instance?

Tags: mule, lifecycle

I use Mule 3.3.0 CE. I wanted to get lifecyle states of a mule instance such as: "Initialising, Starting, Stopping, Disposing". I wanted to store these informations.
these data, there are in "AbstractLifecycleManager" and I don't know how to get them from that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MuleContext class](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.3.1/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/MuleContext.html) has a series of `is...()` methods that you can use to get the current lifecycle state of the Mule application.

Comment: Thanks @David, I use these methods but when my service is stopping or disposing, I want to expose the informations about these events.
I just can expose the informations about "intialising and starting" of lifecyle states.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but if you want to **listen** to lifecycle changes of the `MuleContext` use a "Mule Context Notification Listener" as explained here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Server+Notifications

Comment: I read that link but I can't use it.I want to expose all states lifecyle (initialising, starting, disposing and stopping). when I use `is..()` methods I can expose just two satates (initialising and starting). I think when I stop my service it can't run my configuration and MuleContext class.

Comment: I read mule in action book @David and I find "jmx-notifications" , Can you help me to use it? and Do you think "jmx-notifications" is useful for my project?

Comment: I don't understand why you say you can only expose two states? `isStopping` and `isDisposing` are also exposed. Again, if you want to **listen** to lifecycle changes, re-read my comment above.